# Django filter returning 404

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to get the products that contains a specific word
This is my view

```
class DetailProductAPIViewName(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProductNestedSerializer
    lookup_field = 'description'
    def get_queryset(self):
        description = self.kwargs['description']
        print(description)
        return Product.objects.filter(description__contains=description)
```

And this is my url

```
url(r'^api/product/search/(?P<description>\w{0,50})/$', DetailProductAPIViewName.as_view(),name='list_productsearch_details'),
```

When im printing the description obtained from kwargs, its returning the parameter typed in the url, but in the view its returning

```
 HTTP 404 Not Found
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "detail": "Not found."
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Have you tried using the Django test console to see what your filter returns when you manually give it a string?  `Product.objects.filter(description__contains='something')`

Comment: are you sure description contains that substring , have in you DB ?

Comment: debug Product.objects.filter(description__contains=description) statement and check if it has row(s) in it

Comment: Yeah, im sure it contains that substring, and how can i debug?

Answer (score 0):

Change `contains` to `icontains`,

```
return Product.objects.filter(description__icontains=description)
```

`icontains` returns the case-insensitive results.

Comment: I tried that too, i also tried using startswith and nothing ill just give up i guess, ill try to fix it later thanks for the help